# How can I perfectly emulate the prev/next buttons in slick.js?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

For reference, I'm talking about [Ken Wheeler's Slick slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick).

Having some problems getting "dynamic" (loaded from a database) images showing up when my page is loaded, only the top 20px or so is showing but not the rest for some reason. **If you drag them or click the prev/next buttons they will show fully** and the slider works as it should.

My work-around, thus, is to display a short text saying "Click to show images" that is hidden behind the images if they *do* show up, but displayed if things are buggy.

Since the prev/next buttons are working even when the bug comes up, I figured I'd do this in my click event for the `div-to-fix-bug`:

```
$('.gallery').slick('slickNext')
//gallery is the slider
```

But it won't work, which leads me to believe that the *actual* prev/next buttons do something else! I'm too much of a novice to go through the source code so I'm asking here instead how I can emulate the prev/next buttons better than `slickNext`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to the slickNext, it's better to act before slides change:

```
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  // add your bug-fixing script here and do so only for the relevant slide (nextSlide)
});
```

Wasn't sure what your exact question was, if it wasn't helpful please add a JSFiddle.